# format to currency using toLocalString function not working

Tags: javascript

I am to write a function that is supposed to follow some set of instructions but this doesn’t seem to work.

Here are the instructions

Use the `.toLocaleString` function on its amount and buyerCountry to format amount as a currency with the currency symbol of buyerCountry. The countries and their currency symbols are in the countries array you got in your starter code. If the buyerCountry is not in countries, then 
use United States and the country and format the currency accordingly.

My code below doesn’t seem to comply and im not sure why

```js
const countries = [
  {
      code: "US",
      currency: "USD",
      country: 'United States'
    },
    {
      code: "NG”,
      currency: "NGN”,
      country: “Nigeria”
    }
]

const formatAsMoney = (amount, buyerCountry) => {
  let toCurrency = '';
  countries.forEach(country => {
    try {
      if (value.country === buyerCountry) {
        toCurrency = (amount).toLocalString(value.code, {
          style: 'currency',
          currency: value.currency
        })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toCurrency = (amount).toLocalString(en-US, {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "USD"
      });
    }
  });
  return toCurrency;
}
```

Please what could be the issue and how do i fix this? Thanks

Comment: Post your `value` object also.

Comment: `en-US` looks like it should be a string. Where does `value` come from? I think `value` should actually be `country`. What is the data structure of `countries`?

Comment: It still doesn’t work thanks

Comment: `”` is **not** a valid quote character for string literals and `en-US` (in your `catch` block) should still be `'en-US'`. Please use your browser's console to look for and fix errors.

Answer (score 0):

As you are iterating `countries` array as,

```
countries.forEach(country => {...})
```

You must use `country` to get values like, `country.code` `country.currency` etc.
But instead you are using `value.currency` `value.code` which is typo I think.

Considering your counties array is,

```
const countries = [{
        code: "en-US",
        currency: "USD",
        country: "United States"
    },
    {
        code: "en-NG",
        currency: "NGN",
        country: "Nigeria"
      }
]
```

```
const formatAsMoney = (amount, buyerCountry) => {
    let toCurrency = '';
    let isFound = false;
    countries.forEach(country => {
        if(country.code === buyerCountry) { //I am not sure if you `country.name`, change the key accordingly
          toCurrency = (amount).toLocaleString(country.code, {style: 'currency', currency: country.currency});
          isFound = true;
        }     
      });
     if(!isFound){
        toCurrency = (amount).toLocaleString('en-US', {style: "currency", currency: "USD"}); //here `en-US` should be a string
     }
    return toCurrency;
  }
```

**Note:** You have written `toLocalString` which should be `toLocaleString`, a typo here.

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/basudedazi/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: What does your `buyerCountry` look like? whether it is `en-US` like pattern?

Comment: As you are sending `buyerCountry` = `en-CA` there should be something in your `countries` array to compare with like `code:'en-CA'`

Comment: check the demo now.

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors and a logic problem.

#### Syntax errors

- String literals in JavaScript must be quoted with `'`, `"` or backtick / grave. You cannot use `”`
- Where you have `toLocalString(en-US, {`, en-US should be a string, eg `'en-US'`.
- You have not defined a `value` variable. You probably meant `country`.
- There is no `Number.prototype.toLocalString()` method, you probably meant `toLocaleString()`.

#### Logic errors

You iterate your `countries` array, looking for matches however if no match is found, your program returns an empty string instead of the *en-US* formatted currency. It only does the default formatting if there's an error.

I suggest you use a [*find*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) operation instead of iterating with no early-exit condition.

```js
const countries = [{
  code: "US",
  currency: "USD",
  country: 'United States'
}, {
  code: "NG",
  currency: "NGN",
  country: "Nigeria"
}]

const formatAsMoney = (amount, buyerCountry) => {
  let country = countries.find(({ country }) => country === buyerCountry) || {
    code: 'US',
    currency: 'USD'
  }
  return amount.toLocaleString(country.code, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: country.currency
  })
}

console.info(formatAsMoney(2.15, 'Nigeria'))
console.info(formatAsMoney(2.15, 'UK')) // won't be found
```